# Triathlon suit?

Tags: advice

I know this is little off topic but I cannot find any site on triathlon.
I am looking for to do my first triathlon sprint on **19th March** but there is no triathlon suit available in my city so I will have order it online.

> My budget is under €80

Can any triathlete suggest me some sites and good triathlon suit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about bicycles

Comment: You can try sports.se, but really, none of the SE's are designed for product rec.

Comment: There are loads of triathlon forums. Try (excuse the pun) http://www.220triathlon.com/forum/ for a start.

Comment: The standard rule for stuff is to use new kit at least a couple of times before using in a race.  That goes for food, drink, and gear.  You don't have a lot of time to break in and get used to something before your event.

Comment: Its important that the suit fits correctly as this is how 1) it keeps you warm and 2) doesn't scope water slowing you down. It is very hard to get a good fit without trying one on first.  You may be wasting your money buying one online.

Comment: @rider_x there is no suit available in my city